# How to fill up a dictionary without comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I got a function that is calculating the return money after handing over the payment amount and total cost of the product, it returns a dict with the money values : amount. 
I got now a way with a comprehension to fill the dict up. Is there a way to solve this without a comprehension ?

My Code :

```
COINS = (0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0)
BANK_NOTES = (5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 200.0, 500.0)

def get_return_money (payment_amount,total_price):
    return_money = payment_amount - total_price
    change_money_dict = {}
    for notes_coins in sorted(BANK_NOTES + COINS, reverse = True):
        change_money_dict[notes_coins], return_money = divmod(return_money, notes_coins)
        return_money = round(return_money,2)

    new_dict = {k:v for k,v in change_money_dict.items() if v != 0.0}
    return new_dict
```

Comment: Use a normal formal loop, comprehension's are short hand for loops.

Comment: It will be easier to not add element with zero value rather then clean dict later.

Comment: @OlvinRoght : How do you mean ?

Comment: @Sushanth : I know but how would you do it ?

Comment: @Juan_Gil, write result of `divmod()` into a temporary variable then add element to dict only if return value is not zero.

Comment: @Sushanth comprehensions are not "short-hand for loops". That is a misconception a lot of people run into when they try doing assignments inside comprehensions.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Can you write it down pls ?

Comment: @Juan_Gil, `temp, temp_return_money = divmod(return_money, notes_coins)`